# Python specific parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing my string entirely. I have this string (response from my server):

```
vision = 'item1,item2,,,item5'
```

I'm trying to parse it with this line:

```
list_v = [x for x in vision.split(',') if x.strip()]
```

And I expected :

```
['item1', 'item2', '', '', 'item5']
```

but this line ignore the empty items, I want to know if there is a special way to get all the empty items in my list?

Comment: Then why are you using `if x.strip()` then?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the empty items?

Comment: Oh ok strip() will ignore the empty item ? i read a answer into a topic who explained, that strip will don't ignore them, sorry a didn't read enought documention.

Comment: @RieuxThomas: the `if` section of your loop filters; only items for which the `if` test is true are included. Empty strings are considered false in a boolean test (as do any other sized objects with length 0, numeric 0, `None` and `False`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly filtering using `if x.strip()`. Remove that filter:

```
list_v = [x for x in vision.split(',')]
```

You may still want to strip whitespace from the resulting elements:

```
list_v = [x.strip() for x in vision.split(',')]
```